# Is circle the only shape which just one of it defined by 3 points in a plain

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, discrete-geometry

I'm curious about shapes which **just one** of them is determined by a number of points. From an amazing [theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00151519) in plain curves geometry we know that vertices of triangles similar to arbitrary triangles $T$ is **dense** on every closed jordan curve in a plain, so If $J$ be such curve and $A,B,C$ be 3 noncolinear points on plain then at least one curve similar to $J$ contains $A,B,C$ ,if $J$ be a circle then exactly one circle passes $A,B,C$.

**Question:** is circle the only shape on a **Euclidean** plain (not only from closed curves mentioned above),which **just one similar to it** defined by 3 non-colinear points?*(Means not two or more similar of the shape fits $A,B,C$ ,just one of it).*

**Note:** here the mentioned "shape" can be any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The "trivial triangle" trivially could not be an answer because we can find many similar of it passing through the 3 points creates it as vertices.

What about generalization to $n$ points in **$\mathbb{R}^m$** which exactly define **$k$** similar shapes?

Comment: Parabolas are determined by $3$ points.  See, e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415370/prove-that-three-points-define-a-unique-parabola)

Comment: Your statement needs clarification.  For example an ellipse can be defined by three points, two foci and one end of the major axis.

Comment: @lulu. Isn't the parabola actually determined by 3 points **plus** its axis of symmetry? But the circle only needs 3 points.

Comment: If $v_1-v_0,v_2-v_0,\ldots,v_{n+1}-v_0\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$ linearly independent, then the sphere $S^n=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n+1}~:~|x|_2=1\}$ is uniquely determined by $v_0,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n+1}$.

Comment: A triangle comes to mind.

Comment: @md2perpe  Well, I am looking at parabolas of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$.  If you allow arbitrary forms then, yes, some more information is required.

Comment: I know many shaped can be defined by 3 points, I want to know which shape is unique exept from trivial tiangle and circle.

Comment: Means not two similar of it fits $A,B,C$

Comment: @Mundron Schmidt what is your source and proof for it?

Comment: @lulu: I wrote "axis of symmetry" but meant "direction of the axis of symmetry". By specifying the form you actually specify the direction of the axis of symmetry. So what is given are three points plus the direction of the axis of symmetry.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo: I suppose that you mean that the triangle should have its corners in the three points, not just that the points should be on the triangle (a shape consisting of three line segments).

Comment: @md2perpe Yes. Or you could make infinitely many triangles.

Comment: I have no source, but I'm sure it holds. I think you can prove it by induction.

Comment: @MasM: Could you define 'shape' and what it means for a shape to be determined by three points?

Comment: @MundronSchmidt: there is no connection between the $v_i$ and $S^n$ in your comment. Did you mean to take the vectors $v_i- v_0$ as the orthonormal basis in the definition of $|\cdot|_2$?

Comment: @md2perpe "shape" can be any subset of Euclidean plain $\mathbb{R} ^2$ ,determining by 3 point means by each 3 point on a plain you may consider ,you have a similar to the shape which contains that 3 points.

Comment: Maybe this is a more rigorous interpretation of the question. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of shapes (connected 1 dimensional manifolds with corners equipped with an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^2$). We say that $\mathcal{C}$ has property $\mathcal{P}$ if for every three distinct points $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there exists a unique element of $\mathcal{C}$ that contains $x$, $y$, and $z$. What are some interesting $\mathcal{C}$ that have property $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: @RghtHndSd: But that is too narrow a property because not even the circle has it -- consider three collinear points as $x,y,z$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Who says $\mathcal{C}$ must only contain circles? Let's add lines in.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: Ah -- I understood it to be implicit in the question that $\mathcal C$ has to be exactly an equivalence class under similarity. If you don't require that, then something might indeed be possible.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Ah, interesting condition. I think requiring the three points to be noncollinear is natural too!

Comment: The edit makes the question incorrect as all circles are similar. It takes no points to define a circle up to similarity.

Comment: I think here in this question one things gets mistaken with another for anyone face it for the first. "to be defined by 3 points" is that, but here the more important thing that should be considered is "just one of the shape passes through each three point we may choose first"

Comment: @RossMillikan all parabola $y=x^2$ is also simillar to each others.

Comment: Please clarify the question. The change from one shape to up to similarity makes it not work. I didn’t think there was a problem with Colin ear points for a circle but similarity is too much freedom.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry I didn't get where is unclear. Would you please join a chatroom and discuss.

Comment: I think it might be possible to refine the wording of the question so that the answer is yes, the circle is the only such closed Jordan curve that uniquely fits every such set of 3 points. But I think your admission of "the trivial triangle" at the end ruins the problem. I can't think of a way to set this up so that the problem is satisfied by circles _and_ by "trivial" triangles and by nothing else.

Comment: @David K you're right ,the trivial triangle does not count because we can find many similar to it passing through the the 3 point created it as its vertices, what exactly you mean to refine the question, I think in general ,shapes exist in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which can be considerd as subsets of it and are mentioned in the question ,ultimately will be reduced to closed jordan curve in procedure of finding the answer. You may have solved for closed jordan curve below(I haven't investigated it completely yet) but we may can to eliminate all the other shapes and it needs proof ,so it may doesn't need

Comment: To define and limit the question to a certain class of curves from inception.

Answer (score 2):

A circle in the plane is determined by three numbers.  For example, you can use the two coordinates of the center and the radius.  A point on a curve gives you one number because it takes two numbers to specify the point but you have a degree of freedom in where the point is on the curve.  An axis-aligned square is also determined by three numbers and three points are enough to specify it as long as they are on different sides.  I believe a parabola with a given axis direction will work as well because you can specify it with the coordinates of the vertex and one number for the width.  Three points should suffice here as well.

Comment: For a rigth angled isosceles triangle there are many $y=x^2$ parabola passes through its vertices, pay attention the question states just one of the shape passes through each 3 points you may choose. So parabola is not an answer.

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is three points in non-special position.

Comment: Appreciate your approuch of required numbers to form a shape but here the problem seems more profound than using just this approach.

Comment: @MasM If I give you three collinear points, then there are infinitely many equilateral triangles that pass through all three. So if the points are allowed to be arbitrarily bad, even a triangle is not an answer.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I mentioned the 3 points $A,B,C$ which we consider are not colinear.

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to make the question rigorous and then answer it.
Note that "the trivial triangle" will *not* be an answer to the question under the following formulation.

---

Let a Euclidean plane be given, and let $\mathcal S$ be the collection of sets defined as follows:
a set $\mathcal J$ is a member of $\mathcal S$ if and only if there exists closed Jordan curve $J$ in the given Euclidean plane such that every member of $\mathcal J$ is a closed Jordan curve in the same plane similar to $J,$
and every closed Jordan curve in that plane similar to $J$ is a member of $\mathcal J.$

Let $\mathcal T$ be the collection of all sets of three non-collinear points in the given plane. That is, a set $T$ is in $\mathcal T$ if and only if $T$ contains exactly three members, every member of $T$ is a point in the given plane, and the three points in $T$ are not collinear.

Define a function $k$ on the domain $\mathcal S \times \mathcal T$ as follows:
$k(\mathcal J, T)$ is a set of closed Jordan curves in the given plane,
and a closed Jordan curve $J$ in that plane is in $k(\mathcal J, T)$ if and only if $J \in \mathcal J$ and $T \subset J.$
In other words, $k$ takes any set of similar closed Jordan curves in the plane and any set of three non-collinear points in the plane and returns all the curves within the given set that pass through all the given points.

I interpret the question as asking whether the following claim is true.

**Claim:** Let the set $\mathcal C$ contain all the circles in the given plane and no other members. Then

- the set $k(\mathcal C, T)$ has exactly one member for every $T \in \mathcal T,$ and
- no other set $\mathcal J \in \mathcal S$ has the property that $k(\mathcal J, T)$ has exactly one member for every $T \in \mathcal T.$

That is, there is one and only one member of the set of all circles that passes through any given set of three distinct non-collinear points,
and there is no other set of mutually similar closed Jordan curves (other than circles) that has this property.

**Proof:** Let $\mathcal J$ be a set with the given property. Let $\{A,B,C\}$ be vertices of an equilateral triangle in the plane, and let $J$ be a curve in $\mathcal J$ such that $\{A,B,C\} \subset J.$

Now let $J'$ be the rotation of $J$ that takes $A$ to $B,$ $B$ to $C,$ and $C$ to $A.$ Then $J$ and $J'$ are in $k(\mathcal J, \{A,B,C\}).$
But by assumption, $k(\mathcal J, \{A,B,C\})$ has exactly one element.
Therefore $J' = J,$ and therefore $J$ has three-way rotational symmetry.

Now from $D,$ the center of triangle $\triangle ABC,$ construct a ray $R$ at an arbitrary angle to the ray $DA.$ Let $A'$ be a point where the ray $R$ intersects $J.$ Then there is a transformation consisting of a rotation about $D$ (and possibly a dilation about $D$) that takes $A$ to $A'$ and takes $B$ and $C$ to points on $J.$
Let $J''$ be the image of $J$ under the inverse of that transformation.
Then $\{A,B,C\} \subset J'',$ 
and therefore the assumptions imply that $J'' = J.$

We now know that $J$ is fixed under a set of transformations that include rotation-dilations about $D$ through all possible angles. The only such closed Jordan curve is a circle with center at $D.$

Therefore $\mathcal J$ must contain a circle, and therefore
$\mathcal J = \mathcal C.$

Comment: It seems that this proof only works for equilateral triangle vertices but not for an arbitrarily triple points in euclidean plane.

Comment: The idea here is basically a proof by contradiction. If $\mathcal J$ is a set with the properties you describe, it has to work for _all_ non-collinear sets of three points, including equilateral triangles. I did not even say anything about equilateral triangles in general, I just picked _one_ of them. One should be enough for a counterexample.

Comment: Of course, in order to invalidate this proof, you just have to add a few words to the question; instead of "three non-collinear points," make it "three non-collinear points which are not vertices of an equilateral triangle." So this is not a very satisfying proof, and one that didn't rely on this particular counter-example would be preferable.

Comment: Perhaps if you would rephrase the question in a way that makes it mathematically well-defined, you might get a better answer.