# When two quadratics seems to output the same values are they necessarily the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Joel is thinking of a quadratic and Eve is thinking of a quadratic. Both use $x$ as their variable. When they evaluate their quadratics for $x=1$, they get the same number. When they evaluate their quadratics for $x=2$, they both again get the same number. And when they evaluate their quadratics for $x=3$, they *again* both have the same result. Are their quadratics necessarily the same?

If $x=1$ results in $k_1$, $x=2$ in $k_2$ and $x=3$ in $k_3$ then three equations can be made by inputting these values in $ax^2+bx+c=k_i$

$a+b+c=k_1$

$4a+2b+c=k_2$

$9a+3b+c=k_3$

Using these equations we find the quadratic coefficients in terms of $k_i$:

$a=\frac{k_1-2k_2+k_3}{2}$

$b=\frac{-5k_1+8k_2-3k_3}{2}$

$c=3k_1-3k_2+k_3$

Now I'm stuck on what to do, hitherto I've followed hints but the answer still eludes me.

Comment: After a bit of subtraction I get
\begin{align}
3a+b&=k_2-k_1\\
5a+b&=k_3-k_2\\
\end{align}
what can you do with these equations?

Comment: You're almost all the way there.  You've demonstrated that knowing those three values determines $a$, $b$, and $c$.  So...?

Comment: Think about what would happen if they just evaluate at two points. Then you don't have a unique solution

Comment: Once you've convinced yourself that being given $n+1$ distinct points for a degree $n$ polynomial is enough to uniquely identify the polynomial, another way to think about the polynomial is as $f(x) = k_1\dfrac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(1-2)(1-3)} + k_2\dfrac{(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-3)} + k_3\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(3-1)(3-2)}$ via [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), noting that in the above polynomial if you plug in the corresponding values of $x$ you trivially get the corresponding values of $k$ as the output.  It can be simplified from there as you wish by expanding.

Comment: As for a simpler proof that knowing $n+1$ points for a degree $n$ polynomial is enough to uniquely determine the polynomial... suppose you had two distinct degree $n$ polynomials, $f$ and $g$.  Then $f-g$ is a degree at most $n$ polynomial with at least $n+1$ roots, those roots occurring at exactly those $x$ values that we knew $f$ and $g$ gave the same outputs for.  However, by FTA we know a nonzero degree $n$ polynomial has $n$ or fewer roots, a contradiction.  Therefore $f-g$ must be identically zero and thus the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of a quadratic is a parabola, which is defined by three points, or three inputs and outputs. Since the two quadratics have three inputs which give identical outputs, they must be the same quadratic.

You might be wondering how to prove that a parabola is defined by three points or three inputs and outputs. Here's a link with the exact question: [Prove that three points define a unique parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415370/prove-that-three-points-define-a-unique-parabola)

Hope this helped!